# Select menu WITHIN a Nav menu.. issue of .mouseleave firing when user attempts to use a select menu within one of the submenus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

This is a very convoluted and hard to explain issue, since the menu is unreasonably large and contains things no menu should contain (a few months ago, they stuck videos in it. VIDEOS). One of these things is a select box. I finally got approval to redesign the menu into a more manageable form, but I'm having a really hard time getting the select box to behave. Basically, as soon as it is clicked on to be used, a mouseleave event fires from it's grand-grand parent element, despite the fact that it is actually still IN the relevant element, and hides the submenu the select box is in.
Menu is still in development but I am hitting my head against the wall on this one so any help is appreciated.

Here is the site (the select box is under offices > county offices):

http://www.aces.edu/~sab0037/side-menu.dwt.php

This is still very much a rough draft so please don't bash too heavily on my coding practices, I will be going out and separating my script and css to different files before it is published as well as the menu list. Constructive criticism however is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the source of the problem. I was trying to be proactive in supporting clicks instead of hover, and in doing so, accidentally targeted ALL of the children of the li..

`$('nav>ul>li').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
         $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
         level1HoverEvents($(this));
    }
});`

Which meant, when I clicked in the element, it closed everything. Need to restrict that!

Answer (score 0):

How about preventing the mouseleave when the select gets the focus?

something like this maybe

```
$('.menu').mouseleave(function() {
    var selectFocused = $('select').is(":focus");

    if (!selectFocused) {
      // hide Menu if select doesnt have the focus
    }
});
```

But this would also prevent the menu from closing when you leave the menu while the select is focused.

Comment: That didn't work for me, the following resulted in an alert of foo and the menu still closed -   

`$('nav>ul>li>ul>li').mouseleave(function() {
    var selectFocused = $('nav ul select').is(":focus");
    if(selectFocused) { alert('foo'); }

       if (!selectFocused) {
          $(this).removeClass('show2');
         
       }
    
   });`

Comment: Just checked your site and it seems to work for me now... 

If you found a solution could you post it?

Comment: and now its broken again

Comment: Hey, sorry for leaving this for so long. I have it working in Chrome and Firefox as well as the latest versions of IE. I had another piece of Javascript that I was using to close the menu tabs, and I had accidentally targeted ALL uls.. causing it to automatically close the whole menu when I clicked. Which browser is not working for you?